# naming objects by variables

Tags: c++, object

I am in a situation that I need to make objects in runtime that are named by value of a string, but I can't do that:

```
cin>>input;
className "input"= new className;
```

How can I do that?

> I think it is possible to achieve by using `maps`. Is it true?

Comment: How are you planning to access them if you are allowed to create one??

Comment: yes I need them to change their variables

Comment: Read about macros in c++.

Comment: Yes, it is true that you can use maps for that.

Comment: can u say me how to implement it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590265/how-to-define-a-java-object-name-with-a-variable

Comment: @JeJo That's Java. This question is about c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you can achieve your goal by using `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`)

```
map<string, className*> aMap;//map a string to a className pointer/address
cin>>input;
aMap[input] = new className; //input is mapped to a className pointer
```

Then you can treat `aMap[input]` as a `className*`. e.g.

To call a className method, you can:

```
aMap[input]->aClassNameMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

The object oriented way would be to make name a member of that class and use the input to construct the class.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    std::string myName;
public:
    // Constructor assigning name to myName.
    Foo(const std::string name) : myName(name) {} 

    std::string GetMyName() const
    {
        return myName;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    Foo f(input);
    std::cout << f.GetMyName();
}
```

Also read about new in C++: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)